# Given a set of nodes of a strongly connected graph as input can we get subgraph and path traversal between them

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I have this requirement in ArangoDB AQL: I have a graph created with Document collection for node and Edge collection for directed edge relation.

I want to input a subset of list of nodes as input to AQL query and get all the node traversals /sub graph as the output.

How to achieve this from AQL?
I want to know the relation between given nodes in that way. Please comment if more details are needed.

I know below query now

```
FOR v IN 1..1 INBOUND[or OUTBOUND] 'Collection/_key' EdgeCollection
OPTIONS {bfs: true}
RETURN v
```

Comment: Do you have a sample query you've tried with your data in a working ArangoDB database?

Comment: `FOR v IN 1..1 INBOUND[or OUTBOUND] 'Collection/_key' EdgeCollection
OPTIONS {bfs: true}
RETURN v` is the query , I think its applicable to any example graphs they given in documentation [GOT ancestry] (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Tutorial/Traversal.html) can be extended for more hierarchy and tried upon I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reviewing the queries on the [ArangoDB sample page](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/Cookbook/Graph/ExampleActorsAndMovies.html) where it shows how it performs graph queries, and how to review the results.

In your sample query above you are only returning v (vertex information) as in `FOR v IN`.

That returns only the last vertex from every path that the query returns, it doesn't return edge or path information.

For that you need to test with `FOR v, e, p IN` and it will return extra information about the last edge (e), and the path (p) it took.

In particular look at the results of `p` as it contains a JSON object that holds path information, which is a collection of vertices and edges.

By iterating through that data you should be able to extract the information you require.

AQL gives you many tools to aggregate, group, filter, de-duplicate, and reduce data sets, so make sure you look at the wider language functions and practice building more complex queries.

Comment: I had figured out this yesterday. Although it is cumbersome one can write custom function and do manipulations. Upvoting!

Comment: I try not to write custom function, but perfer to do subqueries or use the `LET abc = (FOR ...` format to load query results into variables. Then you can chain a few LET commands that query the results of other LET commands, and you can very easily work on aggregating and unique path counting, as well as filtering out paths based on verticies or edges in them, or even attributes on those verticies and edges. Once you get the query working, use the 'Explain Query' feature to see if you can optimize performance with indexes, or by breaking complex queries down into smaller chunks.